# Error: import graphlab

Tags: machine-learning, ipython, jupyter-notebook, graphlab

I would like to count with your help, in regards to the following error:

ACTION REQUIRED: Dependencies libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_seh-1.dll not found.

1. Ensure user account has write permission to C:\GraphLab\IntalledPackaged\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab
2. Run graphlab.get_dependencies() to download and install them.
3. Restart Python and import graphlab again.

By running the above function, you agree to the following licenses.

- libstdc++: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html
- xz: http://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob;f=COPYING

Load some house sales data

Dataset is from house sales in King County, the region where the city of Seattle, WA is located.

---

I would like to have your advice in regards to this matter if possible, meaning, what could I do? I already tried : gl.get_dependencies(), and I go these results:

---

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 gl.get_dependencies()
>
> NameError: name 'gl' is not defined

And I already tried to uninstall the software and install it again.
I would thank help in the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fully spell out the prefix "graphlab"; not "gl".
So try graphlab.get_dependencies() and that should import those dependencies for you.
I'm assuming this is your personal machine so you should have write permissions already, but it wouldn't hurt to check that as well if the above doesn't work.